# Does the expression "one in a million type of person" exist?

Tags: idioms

Is it correct to say **"He is a one in a million type of person and student"**, for instance? To praise someone, meaning he is one of a kind. 
What expression would you suggest if it is not? I want to use this phrase in a sort of nomination but I do not know if it even exists, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is something native speakers say.  It's not an especially common expression, but I don't see anything wrong with it.  You can find some examples if you search online.  When I did, I found this quote by the comedian [A. Whitney Brown](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/A._Whitney_Brown):

> There are a billion people in China. It's not easy to be an individual in a crowd of more than a billion people. Think of it. More than a billion people. That means even if you're **a one-in-a-million type of guy**, there are still a thousand guys exactly like you.

To me the phrase sounds somewhat informal.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a proper way to say this is ...

> He's a great person/student. He's one in a million.

Here, the idiom *one in a million means* -nearly unique; one of a very few. Note that you can also say *one in a hundred* but beware, that person might feel this as praising quite less ;)

[Example from [TheFreeDictionary.com]](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/One+in+a+Million)